# Java processing multiple possibly unknown date/time formats

Tags: java, validation, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to create something that can check date/time of many formats to see if its a valid date/time so that I can process it.  Processing it consists of converting the date/time to something normalized for my software to work with.  The problem is that I would have to do a check in different ways to try and detect a date with SimpleDateFormat but it really has been hard to get every variety. The project is related to parsing CSV files with potentially user-specified date formats in a date column.  Is there a better way? Here is what I am doing right now:

```
public static boolean isDateValid(String dateString)
{
    ArrayList<SimpleDateFormat> dateFormats = new ArrayList<SimpleDateFormat>();

    dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy"));
    dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.M.yyyy"));
    dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
    dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.M.yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
    dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
    dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
    dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd hh:mm:ss"));
    dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MMM.yyyy"));
    dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
    dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd"));
    dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("M dd"));
    dateFormats.add(new SimpleDateFormat("M y"));
    for (SimpleDateFormat format : dateFormats) 
    {
        try 
        {
            format.setLenient(false);
            Date date = format.parse(dateString);
            return true;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Additionally I have also tried using DateUtils from apache commons but it seems I would still have to cycle through a bunch of dates.

```
public static boolean isDate(String dateString)
{
    try
    {
        Date theDate = DateUtils.parseDate(dateString);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Any ideas or words of encouragement?

Comment: what do you mean by "but it seems I would still have to cycle through a bunch of dates." ?

Comment: Sorry I meant that I would have to cycle through possible formats still of incoming dates.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your current approach is that you are unnecessarily creating all of those instances of SimpleDateFormat when you know you are only going to use one. Instead, use regular expressions to detect what sort of date string your are receiving and then do one of two things: 1) instantiate only the formatter you need, or 2) manipulate the string to be in a standard format that you can parse with one common formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Well,here is my suggestion:

1. You should narrow down the types of supported date format.It's
   creazy to support every kind of date format,for example,一九九零年三月一日
    is a valid date format in Chinese.
2. And we have a double-check method to detect a valid date as
   following:

   ```
   public boolean isDate(String dateStr, DateFormat format){
       boolean result = false;
       try
       {
           Date date = format.parse(dateStr);
           if (format.format(date).equals(dateStr))
           {
               result = true;
           }
       } catch (Exception e)
       {
           result = false;
       }
       return result;
   }
   ```

Because '2013/4/31' is tranlate to '2013/5/1' by SimpleDateFormat,the last of April is 30th,right?

Answer (score 0):

I was assigned a similar issue at work where i was involved in an ETL process to load data from source file to warehouse. The date formats vary from one source provider to another.
My solution goes with a looping example listed. There is an option to use [**parsePosition**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ParsePosition.html) instead of looping. 
However, there are some ways you can make the looping code better in terms of not instantiating SimpleDateFormat again(Already posted). Instead, just use `applyPattern`.
Also, keeping the various formats in a flat file(config) will make it better to configure and adapt to new formats.
I have posted my implementation at the following [**link**](http://allzhere.in/2013/07/07/java-date-validation-against-multiple-formats/). It might be of some help.

Comment: A problem that one will quickly run into is with ambiguity in the date formats. Even just using the common Western formats, the purely numeric forms can be ambiguous about month vs day depending on the specific date. This is just a tricky problem! If there's any way to push back requirements to your data stream to pick and stick with a date format, do it :-)

Comment: Hi Ron, agreed that fixing things are source is ideal but at times not feasible considering a warehouse would have feeds from various system of records which have their own reasons not to perform any changes. Hence, one must try to achieve the best at their end.